# several files attached/uploaded

Tags: php, file-upload

i'm working on a portfolio management in php, and i've come to the point where i want to be able to attach/upload images when creating a new project. right now, i can only attach one file, but i want to be able to attach more than one file.

so my question is: how can i add a function to my portfolio management which allows me to attach several files?

thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery [Uploadify plugin](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/) for that.

> Uploadify is a powerful and
>   highly-customizable file upload
>   script. In its simplest form,
>   Uploadify is easy to get up and
>   running with minimal effort and little
>   coding knowledge.

Comment: thanks a lot, i will check that out! :) but do you know of any way to do this simply with php?

Comment: @Truls Olsen: Uploadify comes with an example for php too in the downloaded arhive file :)